# How to set a state variable as a new key of an object in another state variable on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

The first state variable is newUser and it's initialized to an empty string. There is a form with an input field to change newUser to whatever the input is. There are also two more state variables: users, which is initialized to `{currentUser: false}`, and userInfo, initialized to `{id: "example", amount: "x", users}` where users is that same state variable.
I'm building a button to add users to the users state variable. onCLick the button calls the following function:

```
const handleAdd = e => {
       
        e.preventDefault();
        setUsers({...users, newUser: false})
        setUserInfo({
            id: "example",
            amount: "x",
            users
        })
        setNewUser("")
    }
```

The problem I'm running into is that instead of adding the value of the variable newUser as a key to the object, the key that is added to the object is newUser.
Ex: if I type "john" into the input field and click the button, users should look like this:

```
{
  currentUser: false,
  "john": false
}
```

and instead it looks like this:

```
{
  currentUser: false,
  newUser: false
}
```

How can I add the actual value of the variable newUser as the key instead of the variable itself?

Comment: FYI you should use `setUsers((prev) => ({...prev, [newUser]: false}))`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead

```
setUsers(user => {...user, [newUser]: false})
```